# code from branch running on master

Tags: git

I'm trying to use git for the first time (after taking an online course on git) as I develop an application in rails. I checked out a branch to work on a feature but when things started going wrong  i wanted to rethink things by taking a look at the application before I checked out that branch, however, I wasn't ready to drop that branch yet. Therefore, I checked out the master branch. however, when I run the application on master branch everything I did in the feature branch is still there. The first time I tried it, I didn't add or commit any files from the feature branch. Then when I saw the changes on master, I went back to the feature branch and did 'git add .' hoping that might keep them in the feature branch before switching back to master. Same result. The broken code I addded in the feature branch is running in the application when I'm on master branch. When I do git status on master branch, it lists all the `Changes to be committed:`, which is the same thing it says if I do git status on the feature branch.

My (perhaps flawed) understanding of git was that if I checked out master without merging code I developed on a branch then code on the branch would not be running on master. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually commit changes to a branch to "keep them there" before switching to master.

Uncommitted changes will follow you from branch to branch (though you'll get an error if they conflict with changes on a branch)

Sidenote: if you're not ready to commit your code to a branch, but you want to keep it around, you can run `git stash`, which will push all of your uncommitted changes onto a stack. Then, later, you can say `git stash pop` to get them back. Be warned, though, that your stash stack follows you around, too, so don't pop onto the wrong branch.